# Check if String array contains word in another String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

Having trouble figuring out how to check if a word from one String Array is in another String Array.  This is what I have so far:

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("TranHistory.csv");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr);

        String[] groceries = new String[]{"albertsons", "costco"};

        for (String[] cols; (cols = reader.readNext()) != null;) {
            if(cols[4].toLowerCase().contains(groceries)){
                System.out.print(cols[4]);
            }

        }
```

The above code is currently giving me an error because .contains() cannot be applied to String Array.  This only works if I change the if statement to this:

```
        if(cols[4].toLowerCase().contains("albertsons")){
                System.out.print(cols[4]);
        }
```

My issue is that String[] groceries is going to have many grocery stores so I think comparing String[] col to String[] groceries is the most efficient way of doing this I'm just having trouble implementing it.

SOLUTION:

I figured it out... you have to do a nested for loop.  This is what I did:

```
String[] groceries = {"albertsons", "costco"};

for (String[] cols; (cols = reader.readNext()) != null;) {
      for (int i = 0; i < groceries.length; i++){

          if(cols[4].toLowerCase().contains(groceries[i]))
             {
                 System.out.print(cols[4]);
                 }

           }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a `Set<String>` containing all of the groceries that you plan to have:

```
Set<String> groceries = Set.of("albertsons", "costco");

for (String[] cols; (cols = reader.readNext()) != null;) {
    if (groceries.contains(cols[4].toLowerCase()){
        System.out.print(cols[4]);
    }
}
```

Searching in a `Set` will not take linear time as it would if you had used an array.

As YCF_L and I explained in the comments below, you can initialize the `Set` in Java 8 with:

```
Set<String> groceries = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("albertsons", "costco"));
```

Comment: `Set#of` was introduced in Java 9.  You should update if you haven't already!

Comment: If you don't want to update (or can't), you can initialize the `Set` with: `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("albertsons", "costco"));`

Comment: ok.. just updated to Java 9 and Set.of is now resolved but there is no output now

Comment: That means that your `Set` does not contain `cols[4].toLowerCase()`

Comment: but I know it does because when I switch the code to this I get the proper output: if(cols[4].toLowerCase().contains("albertsons")){
                System.out.print(cols[4]);
        }

Comment: What else does `cols[4].toLowerCase()` contain?  There must be more characters in it.

Comment: @Stephan, that's using `String.contains()` which is different from the `contains()` in collections. It's basically a substring check.

Comment: Yep, it's not going to be efficient if there isn't some type of delimiter so we can isolate the `String` to what OP wants to search by.

Comment: it contains characters such as this: 

POS COSTCO WHSE #04 CHINO HILLS CA COSTCOO
POS ALBERTSONS STORE 3592 CHINO HILLS CA O

Comment: If all of the `String`s in the array are like that, then you'll need to isolate the `String` you want to search for before using a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically do this via Hashset as it searches the elements in constant time rather than linear time. So you can use this code for searching. I am assuming that you want the whole original array from the file to be printed when found.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("TranHistory.csv");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr);

String[] groceries = new String[]{"albertsons", "costco"};
Set<String> grocerySet = Arrays.stream(groceries).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(grocerySet);
for (String[] cols; (cols = reader.readNext()) != null;) {
    Set<String> smallGrocerySet = Arrays.stream(cols).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    if(grocerySet.containsAll(smallGrocerySet)){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cols));
    }
}
```